# What is the best deep learning framework to implement Generative Adversarial Networks?

Tags: deep-learning

I want to run code for GAN. There are already a lot of codes available for implementation of GAN using Torch, TensorFlow, Theano. Does anyone knows what is the best software framework for implementation of such neural networks?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "best" framework to use as it entirely depends on your requirements. Say for example you are the most comfortable programming in LUA, then you want to take a look at Torch. If you need to deploy it in a mobile environment consider tensorflow. If you are comfortable using a different framework for other neural network applications then consider that one. I personally use pytorch as is it simple to pick up and it is quite easy to debug, but as in everything to do with programming, it all depends on your requirements.

Comment: To me Lua  seems to be more graspable and comprehensible and have already started working with Torch. Thank you for your feedback.